# Disable Html button with JQuery for a period

Tags: jquery, button, javascript

i have a html button, i would like to disable it with jquery, after it was clicked and after like 10 seconds i want to enable it.

```
$('#test').click(function(){
     $("#test").attr("disabled", true);
     $('#test').html('Bitte warten..<img src="<?=CDN('/icons/loading/loading5.gif')?>" />');
});
```

i have problems with the timer part.
I know there is something like `setInterval(function() {}, 5000);` but this will go over and over.

Comment: You can use `clearInterval` to get rid of existing `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setTimout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to enable button after interval.

```
$('#test').click(function(){
     $("#test").attr("disabled", true);
     setTimout(function(){
         $("#test").attr("disabled", false); 
      }, 10000);  
     $('#test').html('Bitte warten..<img src="<?=CDN('/icons/loading/loading5.gif')?>" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

```
$('#some-button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
setTimeout('enableButton()', 5000);

function enableButton(){
   $('#some-button').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setTimeout** function for this:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
     $("#test").attr("disabled", true);
     $('#test').html('Bitte warten..<img src="<?=CDN('/icons/loading/loading5.gif')?>" />');

     setTimout(function(){
          timeOutHit()
      }, 10000);  

});

function timeOutHit()
{
   $("#test").attr("disabled", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See `setTimeout` is the option you want to work with for a specific time period instead.

```
$('#test').click(function(){
   $(this).prop("disabled", true);
   setTimout(function(){
       $(this).prop("disabled", false); 
   }, 10000);  
   $(this).html('Bitte warten..<img src="<?=CDN('/icons/loading/loading5.gif')?>" />');
});
```

But what if work is not done in this time period. If you are using ajax then you can try with `ajaxComplete()` function.

```
$('#test').click(function(){
   $(this).prop("disabled", true);
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
       $("#test").prop("disabled", false); 
   });  
   $(this).html('Bitte warten..<img src="<?=CDN('/icons/loading/loading5.gif')?>" />');
});
```